# How to remove Django HTML code dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, django

I am using "truncatechars" when I want to display texts with more than 600 chars.

What i am doing is: when texts have more than 600 chars I truncate chars to show just a small text, and than I have a "show more" button to show all text.

```
 {{ad.description|truncatechars:"600"}} {% if ad.description|length > 150 %}<a href="#">ver mais...</a> {% endif %}
```

How can I remove the "truncatechars" property dynamically?

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: you dont need the truncatechars here. It would get too complicated. I would just go with a simple jquery solution. Checkout the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to use `truncatechars`. You can do a pure javascript/jquery implementation of this functionality.

There are [plugins](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/) you could use.

OR

If you were to implement it yourself, check [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-shortened-text-show-more-link-jquery/) link out

All you have to do is add a wrapper around `{{ad.description|safe}}`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to 'show more' then you shouldn't use django's template tags at all as they are rendered on the server side. This means that the client (browser) will never get anything more then the first 600 characters. Instead do it with javascript. There are lots of plugins & tutorials that handle this ([here](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/), [here](http://shakenandstirredweb.com/240/jquery-moreless-text) & [here](http://www.jeremymartin.name/projects.php?project=jTruncate) for example)